# Is it possible to create grouping of input cells in IPython Notebook?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

When I do data analysis on IPython Notebook, I often feel the need to move up or down several adjacent input cells, for better flow of the analysis story.

I'd expected that once I'd create a heading, all cells under that heading would move together if I move the heading. But this is not the case.

Any way I can do this?

Edit: To clarify, I can of course move cells individually, and the keyboard shortcuts are handy; but what I'm looking for is a way to group cells so that I can move (or even delete) them all together.

Comment: I guess editing the raw .ipynb file (which is basically json) isn't an option? Do you already use the keyboard shortcuts that the Notebook provides?

Comment: The hierarchical_collapse extension allows one to hide a group of cells. Not what I'm looking for, but quite useful for a long notebook of data analyses. You can get it here:

https://github.com/ipython-contrib/IPython-notebook-extensions/tree/master/testing/hierarchical_collapse

Comment: The successor to hierarchical collapse seems to be [Collapsible Headings](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/tree/master/src/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/nbextensions/collapsible_headings)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I use a little-known extension, which does exactly what you want (i.e. "once I'd create a heading, all cells under that heading would move together if I move the heading"). It is part of the [Calico suite](http://calicoproject.org), but can be installed separately.

More specifically, you need to install a [Calico Notebook Extension](http://calicoproject.org/ICalico#Calico_Notebook_Extensions) named Document Tools. From the description:

> The Calico Document Tools extensions adds section moving, heading numbering, table of contents, and bibliography support.
>   Demonstration of use: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YbM8rrj-Bms

I don't know whether the instructions of installation given on the wiki page are updated for IPython 3.0 (february 2015), but the [source-code on BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/ipre/calico/src/552cdc1bf5508788dac0021c5874fe01fac55f4d/notebooks/nbextensions/?at=master) actually is.

I cannot install IPython 3.0 for the moment, but I gladly use this extension with IPython 2.x since last summer. It's great, perhaps less versatile than the asif.m's suggestion [Collective Cut-Copy-Paste for IPython Notebooks](https://github.com/ivanov/nb-cccp) (which, by the way, has not been updated for IPython 3.0), but IMHO faster and more logical.

Comment: Thanks. I'll report back if it works with IPython 3.0

Comment: This is wonderful. Exactly what I was looking for. No problem with IPython 3 so far. Again, thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the test on IPython 3 :) May I ask you to test another trick which I came accross by reading the code? if I want to keep a section unnumbered, I should be able to prefix the `#`'s run by a space.

Comment: Yes, prefixing the # by a space will keep that heading (but not the entire section) unnumbered. Thanks for the trick.

Comment: @Aristide - Are you able to get this to work with the "Collapsable Heading" add on and other extensions from jupyter_contrib_nbextensions? I ran into problems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44091154/ipython-notebook-extensions-compatibility-issues-b-w-calico-jupyter-contrib-n?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 4):

For anyone out there who needs the grouping feature: yes, there's a great extension here: https://github.com/ivanov/nb-cccp

The days of moving one cell at a time is over. Apparently it will be built into the next IPython version.

Comment: It probably doesn't work with IPython 3 (didn't work with mine anyway). See Aristide's response for a different solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is not currently possible. There are two relevant issues open on Github:

- [Group multiple cells together as one unit using shift button #5180](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/5180)
- [Allow sections to be collapsed and expanded in the notebook #805](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/805)

Comment: Thanks, but the discussion toward the end of #805 mentions extensions being available here: https://github.com/ipython-contrib/IPython-notebook-extensions (I haven't got things to work yet, but looks promising)

Answer (score 2):

> Latest version of Ipython/Jupyter notebook allows selection of multiple cells using shift key which can be useful for batch operations such as copy, paste, delete, etc.