# Determine all files read into and written from an ipython notebook

Tags: python, file-io, ipython, jupyter-notebook

This is a generalization to this question: [Way to extract pickles coming in and out of ipython / jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42288023/way-to-extract-pickles-coming-in-and-out-of-ipython-jupyter-notebook/42288024#42288024)

At the highest level, I'm looking for a way to automatically summarize what goes on in an ipython notebook. One way I see of simplifying the problem is treat all the data manipulations that on inside the notebook as a blackbox, and only focus on what its inputs and outputs are. So, is there a way given the filepaths to an ipython notebook how can you easily determine all the different files/websites it reads into memory and subsequently also all the files that it later writes/dumps? I'm thinking maybe there could be a function that scans the file, parses it for inputs and outputs, and saves it into a dictionary for easy access:

```
summary_dict = summerize_file_io(ipynb_filepath)

print summary_dict["inputs"] 
> ["../Resources/Data/company_orders.csv", "http://special_company.com/company_financials.csv" ]

print summary_dict["outputs"]
> ["orders_histogram.jpg","data_consolidated.pickle"]
```

I'm wondering how to do this easily beyond just pickle objects to include different formats like: txt, csv, jpg, png, etc... and also which may involve reading data directly from the web into the notebook itself.

Comment: You can pickle entire python interactive session using dill: http://trac.mystic.cacr.caltech.edu/project/pathos/wiki/dill.html

Comment: @denfromufa Perhaps I'm missing something ... How would that help explain what's happening in the notebook?

Comment: You probably won't be able to do this without actually executing the notebook.  You can replace __builtin__.open as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/2023709/464289, and if you use the same function to download files, you can just replace that one with a call that logs what you want, and then downloads the file.

Comment: Can someone explain what a pickle is?

Comment: @CharlieG - On pickling: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501947/understanding-pickling-in-python

Comment: Thanks babe you da best @Afflatus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check what files you have opened or modified by patching the builtin `open` as JRG [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42288163/determine-all-files-read-into-and-written-from-an-ipython-notebook#comment72742324_42288163) and you should extend this functionality to patch any functions you use to connect to websites if you want to track that as well.

```
import builtins


modified = {}
old_open = builtins.open


def new_open(name, mode='r', *args, **kwargs):
    modified[name] = mode
    return old_open(name, mode=mode, *args, **kwargs)


# patch builtin open
builtins.open = new_open


# check modified
def whats_modified():
    print('Session has opened/modified the following files:')
    for name in sorted(modified):
        mode = modified[name]
        print(mode.ljust(8) + name)
```

It we execute this in the interpreter (or use it as a module), we can see what we've modified and how we opened it.

```
In [4]: with open('ex.txt') as file:
   ...:     print('ex.txt:', file.read())
   ...:     
ex.txt: some text.



In [5]: with open('other.txt', 'w') as file:
   ...:     file.write('Other text.\n')
   ...:     

In [6]: whats_modified()
Session has opened/modified the following files:
r       ex.txt
w       other.txt
```

This is somewhat limited though, as the mode will be overwritten when a file is reopened, but that can be fixed with some extra checks performed in `new_open`.

Comment: is there was to do this at a more global level.
let's say you use this in a python script that call a script which opens a file