# Installing nodejs for jupyter lab extensions inside Ubuntu on WSL2

Tags: python, node.js, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am quite new to jupyter notebooks. I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 in WSL2 on Windows 10. I have installed `python3.8` and `virtualenv`. Inside new virtualenv (lets call `venv1`), I have installed `ipython`, `jupyter`, `jupyterlab`.

I want to do following:

1. Auto number my notebook sections based on headings
2. Auto generate table of contents
3. Move sub headings together when heading is moved

I came across [this extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24895714/is-it-possible-to-create-grouping-of-input-cells-in-ipython-notebook) (call it `ext0` [video tut](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YbM8rrj-Bms)) which seem to do exactly the same. However, I havent tried it, as I immediately came across [jupter lab's extesions](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/extensions.html) and specifically following two extensions:

[image]

Call the first extension above `ext1` and second  `ext2`.
Clicking `ext1` link opens [this](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-toc) which looks quite correct. Clicking `ext2` links opens [this](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab), which is jupyterlab's main directory and hence does not seem to be an extensions directory. I am not able to figure it out which one I should install. I can try both. But I am not able to, as clicking install opens of this error message:

[image]

The extension site [asks](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/extensions.html) to install it using `conda`. However, I have not used conda earlier. Can I install node in some other way. I tried to install by doing `pip install nodejs` and then restarted jupyter lab. But am still not able to install extensions. Can it be only done using `conda`?

Also, I am connecting to jupyter notebooks running in `venv1` inside WSL using vscode. I guess this also creates node server for vscode and WSL interaction, as I can see it in the Windows Task Manager. Will this conflict with nodejs installed for jupyter lab extensions?

Comment: Did you find a good solution?

Comment: Check the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65787735/1317018) to this question. Also I have asked another question facing same issue while installing debugger in jupyter and answered it myself. Check both question and answer in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66721573/installing-jupyter-debugger-in-non-conda-pipenv-environment/66721654). These should help. (PS: I tried referencing Windows node from WSL. I guess you should install node in WSL only as suggested in answer below. But, anyways, referencing Windows node from WSL also seem to work as I answered in that thread)

Answer (score 4):

Using Ubuntu

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_15.x | sudo -E bash -

sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Using Debian, as root

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_15.x | bash -

apt-get install -y nodejs
```

---

FROM this link: [Installation instructions](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#debinstall)

Comment: I confirm that this works on Ubuntu 20.04 using the latest `_16.x` version.