# Installing jupyter debugger in non conda / pipenv environment

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I have installed jupyter lab using `pipenv install jupyter lab`.
But while creating new notebook, it did not show xpython kernel option.
So explicitly installed xpython kernel using `pipenv install xeus-python`.
I also excuted `pip install notebook` as recommended by xeus-python [docs](https://xeus-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#from-pypi).
Now I am able to create notebooks with xpython kernel:

[image]
[image]

However I am not able to enable debugging. That is my UI dont have enable debugging button:
[image]

Trying to install debugger extension from lab gives this error:
[image]

So I installed node on my windows 10. But `node` and `npm` were not accessible from `pipenv` environment:

```
(pipenv_env) F:\user\workspaces\pipenv_env>node    
'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

(pipenv_env) F:\user\workspaces\pipenv_env>npm    
'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
 operable program or batch file.
```

So, I set path:

```
(pipenv_env) F:\user\workspaces\pipenv_env>SET PATH=C:\Program Files\Nodejs;%PATH%
```

Then I was able to install the extension as stated [here](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/extensions.html):

```
(pipenv_env) F:\user\workspaces\pipenv_env>jupyter labextension install @jupyterlab/debugger
Building jupyterlab assets (production, minimized)
-
(pipenv_env) F:\user\workspaces\pipenv_env>jupyter labextension list
JupyterLab v3.0.12
Other labextensions (built into JupyterLab)
    app dir: C:\Users\user\.virtualenvs\pipenv_env\share\jupyter\lab
        @jupyterlab/debugger v3.0.8 enabled ok
```

But still I am not able to get the debugger button in jupyter lab, even after restarting the jupyter lab from the same terminal where I have set the path to node.

Does debugging in jupyter work only with conda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching to jupyter lab extension manager tab, it said build is needed:

[image]
(above image is from google search, my extension manager had debugger listed)

I let it complete the rebuild.

Then, I quickly tried to create new cell and run it with xpython pernet, but jupyter lab kept saying `Connecting to kernel...` for some time and then switched to `No kernel` status. So, I realise there is some issue with kernel now. I checked console and found following logs:

```
[I 2021-03-20 17:44:39.684 ServerApp] Kernel started: 81e125aa-9fcc-4f15-9a23-efa802f0f7b4
[I 2021-03-20 17:44:51.754 ServerApp] AsyncIOLoopKernelRestarter: restarting kernel (4/5), new random ports
f:\programfiles\python37\python.exe: No module named xpython_launcher
[W 2021-03-20 17:44:54.773 ServerApp] AsyncIOLoopKernelRestarter: restart failed
[W 2021-03-20 17:44:54.773 ServerApp] Kernel 81e125aa-9fcc-4f15-9a23-efa802f0f7b4 died, removing from map.
[W 2021-03-20 17:45:10.187 ServerApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from 410fab88-88ee-4325-917f-f903903c51ac
[E 2021-03-20 17:45:10.188 ServerApp] Error opening stream: HTTP 404: Not Found (Kernel does not exist: 410fab88-88ee-4325-917f-f903903c51ac)
```

So I did quick google and came across [this](https://github.com/jupyter-xeus/xeus-python/issues/382) issue. Changing `python.exe` to `python` in the file `C:\Users\user\.virtualenv\pipenv_env\share\jupyter\kernels\xpython\kernel.json` worked:

```
{
  "display_name": "Python 3.7 (XPython)",
  "argv": [
      "python",
      "-m",
      "xpython_launcher",
      "-f",
      "{connection_file}"
  ],
  "language": "python",
  "metadata": { "debugger": true }
}
```

Now, I am getting enable debugging button and also able to add breakpoint and debug.

[image]